# Scrapy: the scrapy server requires a project, why?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to run scrapy server with this command:

```
scrapy server
```

It failed because there is no project.Then I create an empty project to run server, an deploy another project successfully. But, scrapy server cannot work with this project, and tell me it cannot find the spider. Why? It means I must run a different server with each project?

Comment: I believe yes, you can run multiple spiders in one project but only one project per instance of scrapy.

Comment: The [`Scrapy server`](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#projects-and-versions) *"can manage multiple projects"*.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you created a spider under one project, and need it in another project. To do that, you can just copy the `spider.py` file.

Another option is to get by without the server, that depends on what you want to do. [That's discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954677/crawling-local-files-with-scrapy-without-an-active-project)