# Crawling local files with Scrapy without an active project?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, local

Is it possible to crawl local files with Scrapy 0.18.4 without having an active project? I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385837/python-scrapy-on-offline-local-data) answer and it looks promising, but to use the `crawl` command you need a project.

Alternatively, is there an easy/minimalist way to set up a project for an existing spider? I have my spider, pipelines, middleware, and items defined in one Python file. I've created a scrapy.cfg file with only the project name. This lets me use `crawl`, but since I don't have a spiders folder Scrapy can't find my spider. Can I point Scrapy to the right directory, or do I need to split my items, spider, etc. up into separate files?

[edit] I forgot to say that I'm running the spider using `Crawler.crawl(my_spider)` - ideally I'd still like to be able to run the spider like that, but can run it in a subprocess from my script if that's not possible.

Turns out the suggestion in the answer I linked does work - http://localhost:8000 can be used as a start_url, so there's no need for a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an option, you can *run Scrapy from a script*, here is a [self-contained example script](https://gist.github.com/alecxe/fc1527d6d9492b59c610) and the [overview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27744766/771848) of the approach used.

This doesn't mean you have to put everything in one file. You can still have `spider.py`, `items.py`, `pipelines.py` - just import them correctly in the script you start crawling from.